# best windows based network monitoring software

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2008, monitoring

i want to know which is best windows based network monitoring tools mainly for monitoring network and control internet access.

i want to monitor the bandwidth of internet usage in each machine in network.
websites accessed by each machine.

is there any there is any opensource tools.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Once, I faced some problems with bandwidth. Which is that situation where too many users in a network causes lag and delay. Therefore I've search some solutions from my friends from abroad.

You can try this link to download the software which can control your network bandwidth as long as the pc is connected to the network.

---

http://www.netsoft2005.com/en/

---

It is called P2Pover, some kind of open-sourced software to monitor the network.
Dun worry, it's free =)

Comment: I checked this software.it is simple and good.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a sniffer like WireShark or Network Monitor wouldn't help in that case, I guess.

Assuming you are in some kind of intranet with few uplinks to the internet, I'd suggest to configure the router that sits at this boundary to force traffic for certain ports (such as 80 for HTTP) through a transparent proxy (lighttpd, nginx and Apache with mod_rewrite can do that easily). That would satisfy the part about monitoring what gets accessed. However, for the amount traffic itself I have no immediate idea, except using the router to log that as well.